# Golang embed html from file

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

How can I do in Golang if I have an HTML file like this:

```
<html>
  <head lang="en">

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>{{.Header}}</header>
    <div class="panel panel-default">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I want to embed a part of code into to header tags from an other file like this:

```
<div id="logo"></div><div id="motto"></div>
```

My try:

```
header, _ := template.ParseFiles("header.html")
c := Content{Header: ""}
header.Execute(c.Header, nil)

index := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))
index.Execute(w, c)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is it not working? Please post a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @R4PH43L I refreshed the post with my try.

Comment: You've got two possibilities:use nested template (find into https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/ and name of nested template will be header.html) or use template.HTMLEscapeString. I would prefer first one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you parse all your template files with [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) or with [`template.ParseGlob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseGlob), the templates can refer to each other, they can include each other.

Change your `index.html` to include the `header.html` like this:

```
<html>
  <head lang="en">

  </head>
  <body>
    <header>{{template "header.html"}}</header>
    <div class="panel panel-default">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then the complete program (which parses files from the current directory, executes `"index.html"` and writes the result to the standard output):

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html", "header.html")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index.html", nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

With `template.ParseGlob()` it could look like this:

```
t, err := template.ParseGlob("*.html")
// ...and the rest is the same...
```

The output (printed on the console):

```
<html>
  <head lang="en">

  </head>
  <body>
    <header><div id="logo"></div><div id="motto"></div></header>
    <div class="panel panel-default">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```