# How to include separate header file in each html file containing by a folder?

Tags: php, html, go, include

I want to include a single html header file `header.html` in each rest of the files in the folder while using php localhost we use `<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` just change the extension and use it everywhere but now I'm using the * ***golang*** and I don't know how to include the `header.html` file in each of the html file. I will done this for once write individually because there two files but if there are 50 files of html then its very time taken to write the code individually. How to include a single file of html header in the rest of the html files in folder?

The code I'm using is

html file

```
<body>
 <header>{{template "bootstrap_header.html"}}</header>
<h3>Login Here</h3>
 <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="enter your email here">
 <input type="text" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="enter your password here">
 <button id="button_first">Click it for Login</button>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').on('click', function(e){
            var email = $('#email').val()
            var password = $('#password').val()
            $.ajax({
                    url:"/api/v2/login",
                    type:"POST",
                    data: {'email':email, "password":password},
                success: function(results) {
                    console.log(results)
                    if(results.response.message === "Success"){
                        console.log("hello")
                        alert(results.response.message);
                        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
                            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";path=/";
                        }
                    setCookie("X-Test-Header", results.response.total_record)
                    document.location.href = "/api/v1/customer?Number="+results.response.data[0]._id;
                    }
                    if(results.response.message === "Failure"){
                        console.log("hello")
                        alert(results.response.data);
                    }
                }   
            });
        });
    });
 </script>
</body>
```

This page will redirect me at the given url `document.location.href = "/api/v1/customer?Number="+results.response.data[0]._id;`

Go code

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles("buttons.html", "bootstrap_header.html")
if err != nil { 
    panic(err)  
}

err = t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "buttons.html", nil)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Gives me output as in terminal

```
Both file code in the terminal
```

> Expected output is to display it in the browser

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33984147/golang-embed-html-from-file

Comment: @priya its just show me the html in the terminal but i want this header will display in the browser i edit my question and then you will see

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816039/html-partials-in-golang

Comment: @Priya  sorry to say but i am not getting this example actually i am using `gin package` :(

Comment: `os.Stdout` is standard output not the browser.

Comment: If you're using `gin` you should pass [`c.Writer`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Writer) whenever you want to write a response back to the client (browser).

Comment: Thanks @priya for helping me

Comment: thanks @mkopriva For helping me.